# Declaring external types for Python (mypy)

Tags: python, mypy

I'm writing Python scripts for a tool with embedded IronPython. This tool injects a number of it's own variables into the IronPython global scope, for example a function called `resources`.

When I write scripts I get many false-positive linter errors about undefined variables.

Is there a way to suppress these errors for the variables defined by the tool?

I'm looking for something equivalent to a typescript definition file (*.d.ts ). I want to tell my editor that these variables exists, and (optionally) what their type is, but do not want to initialise their values (as this would overwrite the definitions the tool provides).

One thought I had was to optionally initialise these variables in my script, such that they are only initialised when they do not exist (thus not overwriting the tool's definitions at run-time). e.g.

```
if resources is None:
    resources = None  # type: (str) -> object
```

But this doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, you'll need to lie to mypy in one form or another -- the question just boils down to what the ergonomic and convenient way of doing so will be.

Probably the most convenient way of doing this might be to just define your extra in a separate file and globally import them into your script. You can do this without actually polluting your environment by taking advantage of the `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` variable -- that variable is always False at runtime but is treated as being true at type-check time. So, you'd maybe do something like this:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from my_ironpython_globals import *
```

It would probably be a good idea to make sure nobody actually tries using anything from your custom module at runtime, however. One way you can ensure this is by defining all of the extra variables/functions in a [stub file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stubs.html) -- stub files are Python's analog to TypeScript's definition files.

In short, create a file ending with a `.pyi` extension (instead of `.py`) within your project and define everything there.

If you'd like to see examples of what stub files tend to look like, try checking out [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), a repository of stubs for the standard library and some popular 3rd party libraries. (Mypy comes baked in with a copy of typeshed). Their [contribution guidelines](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#stub-file-coding-style) has a style guide, if you're interested in that sort of thing.

If you'd like to distribute your newly-created stubs as a 3rd party module that you can just pip-install and use, create a [PEP 561-compliant package](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installed_packages.html) containing your type hints.

---

Another approach you could take is using your own custom version of typeshed. That is, clone or fork [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) and modify the `stdlib/*/builtins.pyi` files so they contain the ironpython-specific globals.

Then, invoke mypy by using the `--custom-typeshed-dir` flag: e.g. do `mypy --custom-typeshed-dir path/to/my/typeshed mycode`.

If typing this sequence of flags gets tedious, create a [configuration file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html) and encode your setting there.

This approach is a little more principled then the first one in that you're teaching mypy to legitimately recognize any available globals. However, having to maintain your own fork of typeshed + keep up with upstreamed changes *is* a lot of work (and this kind of fragmentation probably isn't ideal).

So, if you do decide to take this approach, it might be worth first having a discussion on typeshed's issue tracker first. Typeshed (and the PEP 484 ecosystem) is still pretty new in general, so there's still room to influence the direction in which it grows.